# Content Organizer Rules not routing when uploading multiple files

Tags: content-organizer, drop-off-library, content-organizer-rule

Hi All : ) The behaviour I'm experiencing is when uploading multiple files using the Document Centre, files are being routed to a generic Document Library. *This is not a rule I've set.* **It's not using the routing rules at all**. In any combination, I've now only got one rule active, which is testing ie. Property: Keywords, 
Operator: Is equal to,
Value: test.

I've set the target location etc. I'm using Sp2010 Enterprise. my event timer runs every 30 minutes. OOTB solutions please, I've not got access to Visual Basic. I don't see anyone else with the same issue.  Thank you for your time.

Comment: This issue resolved itself, - It now routes the Documents as expected, I wonder if it was a night timer job schedule issue.  I set the rules to work on content type Document - with destination libraries to have that document CT, and route if the name contains all of, 'Acme'. This site details many of the problems in SP 10 Content Organiser .  
www.get-sp.com/2014/05/problems-with-content-organizer-10.html